# how can I extrude curve shapes onto curve without tapering

Tags: extrude, bezier-curves

I'm stuck. Can't figure out how I can extrude a closed curve onto a NURBS curve without it looking tapered.

I notice that when it's set to "2D" there is no tapering, but I want to do it on 3d.

Thanks for help.[image]

Comment: Hi there, I am involved in addressing this issue in Blender. This is still in development but closing in on a solution and that'd be great if you could provide some feedback here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-to-mesh-node-even-thickness-feedback-thread/27271  - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's a known limitation of the current system, there is currently no elegant workaround for this as far as I know.

1. Either use only separate 2D curves for each segment (rotate them in object mode to their correct positions)
2. Add extra control vertex close to corners to minimize the tapering distance (clumsy and may not look good)
   [image: Extra control vertex]
3. Or use independent splines inside the same bezier curve for each segments (may cause intersection artifacts under certain circumstances)
   [image: Separate splines]

Choose the lesser evil for your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

In the *Object Data* tab in the *Properties panel* (pictured in your screen shot), under *Shape > Resolution: > Preview U:*, change the number from 1 to 64 (the max). Leaving the *Render U:* at zero will cause it to use the *Preview U:* (just fine).

Also, make sure that you have added enough loop cuts to your cylinder so that it deforms properly.

Comment: Hi Shady. I added resolution but no change. It still tapers. I wanted to be able to sweep a closed shape ( moulding ) into a curve.

Comment: Could you add more details/a .blend file? I answered the question I saw, but please correct me if I answered the wrong thing.