# Making sharp corners with bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curves

Is there a way to create sharp corners without overlapping?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53475/how-can-i-extrude-curve-shapes-onto-curve-without-tapering/53486#53486