# bezier curve with bevel object: nice corner

Tags: bezier-curves

A bezier curve with a bevel object and a bend with a free vertex.
How is the bend made nice with a continious width?
The increase of resolution (Data > Geometry > Bevel > Resolution) smoothes the bends of 2D curves, no effect on 3D curves.
[image]

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: If you go to the Data of your Bezier Curve > Shape > Resolution and increase the Preview and Render factor, it will improve the angle

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53475/how-can-i-extrude-curve-shapes-onto-curve-without-tapering and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-sweep-with-bevel-object-in-bezier-curve3d-pipe/

Comment: Hi there, I am involved in addressing this issue in Blender. This is still in development but closing in on a solution and that'd be great if you could provide some feedback here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-to-mesh-node-even-thickness-feedback-thread/27271  - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As *Duarte Farrajota Ramos* commented, it isn't possible as a 3D-curve at the moment.
However, you can use seperate 2D-curves (see the links in the comments) or make at least the left joint of the corner horizontal:

Use shrink/fatten (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) to fatten it by the factor $\sqrt{2}\approx1.41421$

[image]