# Curve bevel not working properly, my mesh ends up deformed

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel, curve-modifier

I cant seem to figure out why this happens.....Applied a bevel to this curve set to OBJECT and then I selected my profile I have imported. Somehow it ends up deformed.I have applied scale.

[image: The problem]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to your question into the field on that page and it will then appear in your question.

Comment: First thing, on the top of the Object Data panel, switch the Shape from 3D to 2D, if this is not your problem, in Edit mode select all and right click > Set Curve Radius >  1 and Enter

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/113888/bezier-curve-with-bevel-object-nice-corner