# Creating pipes with a bezier

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to create pipes, however, I don't understand how the bezier works so I've only been able to create pipes with some simple extrusion. I would like to know how I would like to know how to create angles and such with a bezier.

Down below I've added what my pipes currently look like and the reference picture.

[image]

[image: Reference picture]

Comment: would you be willing to use a mesh and just use the spin function?

Comment: Hi. When you say "I don't understand how the bezier works", what does that mean? That you add a curve but don't know how to extrude? Please be specific with where you are getting stuck. Thanks.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53475/how-can-i-extrude-curve-shapes-onto-curve-without-tapering/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for is the bezier geometry menu:

[image: the bezier menu]

After you create the curve which you want to make into a pipe, you can change the depth and resolution to edit the thickness and amount of faces here. Also, to make the bezier curve look like a pipe you will need to set the shape to 3D and the fill to full. This is an example:
[image: finished pipe]

If you are confused about creating the bezier curve in the first place, you would add a bezier curve (shift+a, bezier curve), and then enter edit mode (tab). Here you can select the control line things, and move/rotate/scale using the usual blender controls. To add another control line you would use "e".

Hope this helped

If you need more clarification check out this video specifically about creating pipes using beziers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMXcQ2V-VGA

Comment: very good answer.