# Creating and Animating Line Segments?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a zig-zag figure I want to import and manipulate in Blender, preferably on a segment-by-segment basis.

The canonical method for doing "line art" in Blender appears to be to create a curve object then, in the Properties, crank up the Bevel Depth to a suitable value.  The problem is that, for "curves" having hard, acute angles, you end up with a very thin, distorted shape.

Here's an example curve.  All handles are set as vectors:

[image: Basic curve]

Here's the same curve with a bevel applied.  Note how the generated tube is flattened, making it nearly invisible when viewed along the Z-axis.  The sharper the angles, the thinner the resulting tube:

[image: Beveled curve]

I'd like uniform "thickness" no matter what angle I view it from (particularly along the Z-axis).  How can I best achieve this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53475/how-can-i-extrude-curve-shapes-onto-curve-without-tapering/53486#53486 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/can-i-extrude-a-path-in-x-y/87254#87254 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-sweep-with-bevel-object-in-bezier-curve3d-pipe/56115#56115 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better/66367#66367

Answer (score 3):

This mesh is maden by 7 vertices only, with a skin modifier. Tweak the thickness with Mean Radius values, and don't forget to select one of the starting vertices and use the "Mark Root" function on the skin modifier.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**If** the original curve is planar, then a 2D curve (right) will miter correctly where a 3D curve won't:

[image]

In that case, you can set the curve to 2D in its geometry panel.