# Uneven thickness when using bevel object along a curve

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I want to add even thickness to a zig-zagged line.
[image: zig-zagged line]
 Therefore, I converted the line to bezier curve and used another beziercircle as a bevel object. The result is uneven thickness as below. 
Any ideas on how to fix it? or other ideas on how to create the pipe-like thickness from my zig-zagged line?

[image: UNEVEN THICKNESS]

Comment: Is the scale of your bezier objects uniform (1,1,1) ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-sweep-with-bevel-object-in-bezier-curve3d-pipe/56115#56115 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53475/how-can-i-extrude-curve-shapes-onto-curve-without-tapering/53486#53486