# Problem with Curve Modifier on object array

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

when I try to apply Curve Modifier on my air duct object, the corners get weird, no matter how many cuts the object has.

Can somebody explain how I can fix it? Pls

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better/66367#66367 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53475/how-can-i-extrude-curve-shapes-onto-curve-without-tapering/53486#53486

Answer (score 0):

Curve modifier needs a subdivided,  the more the better, mesh to work as expected. Instead, use Bevel object which is a bezier circle with handles set to vector to form a square. Then rotate it and make a rectangle.