# Why is this bevel inconsistent after converting edges to curves? (attempting to make a ladder)

Tags: bezier-curves

I have applied all transforms before converting to curves. The left side of the ladder looks like what I am aiming for, but the right pole seems to have some squished spots. I am thinking that maybe there is a way I can get the curve directions to be more consistent? Google searching has helped me understand the curve directions, but I cannot identify what I need to do to these curve points to get the desired consistency. Any possible ideas?

Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53475

Comment: Curves won't be connected in this situation. Try to use *"wireframe"* or *"skin"* modifiers instead.

Comment: Hi there, I am involved in addressing this issue in Blender. This is still in development but closing in on a solution and that'd be great if you could provide some feedback here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/curve-to-mesh-node-even-thickness-feedback-thread/27271  - Thanks in advance!