# Blender Curves Square Cross Section

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to make a square pipe of a square curve.

Every time I make a square pipe I get a cross-section of a pipe as a rectangle.

Switching the curve shape to **2D** got me the desired result but as soon as I applied the transformation operations I got the error **"Rotation/Location can't apply to a 2D curve"**.

All I want is to get a square cross-section of a pipe using curves.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56079/how-can-i-make-a-perfect-sweep-with-bevel-object-in-bezier-curve3d-pipe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53475/how-can-i-extrude-curve-shapes-onto-curve-without-tapering/